# XSLT how to get value when variable equals Node name?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I inherited an XSLT 1.0 project and I don't know much XSLT.

I have an external XML file with a list of codes. I want to use this file to get the value of a node based on a variable. When $source = "AFW", I want to get "XML-AP", and when $source = "SAGITTA", I want to get "XML".

The partial listing of the XML lookup file:

```
<codes name="AcordToMSA_CodeLists">
    <Source>
        <codes>
            <AFW>XML-AP</AFW>
            <SAGITTA>XML</SAGITTA>
        </codes>
    </Source>
</codes>
```

The XSLT for theXML lookup file:

```
<xsl:variable name="lookupFileSource" select="document('XSL/AcordToMSA_CodeLists.xml')/codes" />



<Home>
    <xsl:variable name="source" select="Top/ClientApp/Name"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="Source"><xsl:value-of select="$lookupFileSource/Source/codes[local-name() = 'AFW']"/></xsl:attribute>
</Home>
```

The attribute line I have above returns an empty string. What do I need to do to get the value for a node when the $source variable is equal to the node name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the element child's `local-name`, so

```
<xsl:attribute name="Source"><xsl:value-of select="$lookupFileSource/Source/codes/*[local-name() = 'AFW']"/></xsl:attribute>
```

Answer (score 0):

> When $source = "AFW", I want to get "XML-AP", and when $source = "SAGITTA", I want to get "XML".

I believe that would translate to:

```
<Home>
    <xsl:attribute name="Source">
        <xsl:value-of select="$lookupFileSource/Source/codes/*[name()=$source]"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</Home>
```

or shortly:

```
<Home Source="{$lookupFileSource/Source/codes/*[name()=$source]}"/>
```